# Laravel webapp login from iOS with Facebook SDK

Tags: php, ios, facebook, laravel, oauth

i have a webapp working with Laravel.
i have some users registered in my webapp.
users who dont want to create a account can use Facebook/Google+ login.

to make Facebook/Google+ connection, i used a oAuth2 connexion with :
[oauth-4-laravel](https://github.com/artdarek/oauth-4-laravel)

on the iOS application, users can login using username and password but they can login too with Facebook/Google+ using FB/G+ SDK.

my questions is, how to login on my webapp users from iOS who are connected by Facebook/Google+.

artdarek/oauth-4-laravel require a "code" given by the social network, and i dont know how to get it on iOS.

here the code for users who want to connect to the webapp by web browser :

```
 public function loginWithFacebook() {

// get data from input
    $code = Input::get( 'code' );

    // get fb service
    $fb = OAuth::consumer( 'Facebook' );

    // check if code is valid

    // if code is provided get user data and sign in
    if ( !empty( $code ) ) {

        // This was a callback request from facebook, get the token
        $token = $fb->requestAccessToken( $code );

        // Send a request with it
        $result = json_decode( $fb->request( '/me' ), true );

       // $message = 'Your unique facebook user id is: ' . $result['id'] . ' and your name is ' . $result['name'];
        //echo $message. "<br/>";

        //Var_dump
        //display whole array().
       // dd($result);
        if (User::where('fb_id','=', $result['id'])->count() == 0) {
             $user = new User;
            $user->firstname = $result['first_name'];
            $user->lastname = $result['last_name'];
            $user->username = $result['email'];
            $user->email = $result['email'];
            $user->fb_id = $result['id'];
            $user->yearofbirth = substr($result['birthday'],6,9);
            $user->fk_role=3;

            if ($result['gender'] == 'male') {
                $user->sex = 1;
            }
            else{
                $user->sex = 0;
            }


            $user->save();

        }
        else{
            $user = User::where('fb_id','=', $result['id'])->first();

        }

    Auth::login($user);

    Userslog::log('desktop_facebook_login');

    return Redirect::to('/')->with('message', 'Logged in with Facebook');

    }
    // if not ask for permission first
    else {
        // get fb authorization
        $url = $fb->getAuthorizationUri();

        // return to facebook login url
         return Redirect::to( (string)$url );
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

i finally find a solution in the issues of oauth-4-laravel on github,

i just have to use iOS AccessToken and connect the user to the webapp using this token.

here the code laravel code to use the Token ;)

```
use OAuth\OAuth2\Token\StdOAuth2Token;

$token_interface = new StdOAuth2Token(Input::get( 'token' ));       
$network = OAuth::consumer( 'Facebook' );
$network->getStorage()->storeAccessToken('Facebook', $token_interface);
$result = json_decode( $network->request( '/me' ), true );
$fb_id = $result['id'];
```

To Resume,
the best way is  ; to login with Facebook/Google+ on iOS,

when login finish with success, get the AccessToken and send to the webapp.And then the webapp use you token to login again the user to Facebook/Google+ and finally , the user is verified and you can login it to laravel webapp.

have a nice day.

Answer (score 0):

I'm quite in the same situation here.

With the solution you provide, how are you preventing other applications to send their own AccessToken and access your Laravel application?

I assume you send the token via a POST request from you iOS app to a certain endpoint of your Laravel app, therefore any developper knowing this endpoint could pretend to be logged on your mobile application, no?

Comment: after login with facebook or google, users are logged on laravel Authentification system with laravel account. iOS users need to be connect to the laravel login to use my application.

developper can login on my application, it will be open for every people.

Have I answered your question? if no, can you give me more details.

Comment: on facebook application management, you can enable login only for you ;)

Comment: Thanks for the enlightenment :)